# Some keybinding stopped working this morning with error "Wrong type argument: arrayp, nil"

Tags: error-handling, counsel

I used `counsel-org-goto-all` to jump between headings. This morning, the command (which I have bound to `C-;`) stopped working with this error: `Wrong type argument: arrayp, nil`.

I have searched on the internet a bit, and [found this fix](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/11152):

```
(setq projectile-keymap-prefix (kbd "C-c C-p"))
```

But it does not seem to fix anything for me.

I did some debugging and got this trace from the error after setting `debug-on-error` to `t`.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument arrayp nil)
  replace-regexp-in-string("\\[[0-9]*\\(?:%\\|/[0-9]*\\)\\]" " " nil)
  counsel-outline-title-org()
  counsel-outline-candidates((:outline-title counsel-outline-title-org :action counsel-org-goto-action :history counsel-org-goto-history :caller counsel-org-goto) nil)
  counsel-org-goto-all()
  funcall-interactively(counsel-org-goto-all)
  call-interactively(counsel-org-goto-all nil nil)
  command-execute(counsel-org-goto-all)
```

But I don't know enough elisp and emacs to figure out what is going on.

I don't even know what the error means. Does it mean `arrayp` was expected and `nil` was received? The error seems cryptic.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: What's going on is that something in `counsel-outline-title-org`, or something it calls, is calling `replace-regexp-in-string` with a `nil` 3rd arg, and the 3rd must be a string. Maybe a bug in the counsel code. Consider reporting it. But first start Emacs using `emacs -Q`, and try to repro the problem, to be sure it's not coming from something in your init file.

Comment: @Drew I tried the `emacs -Q` command, but it does not load anything. I tried loading init.el (my init file), but then something funky happened. If I opened just one file with emacs -Q, the error did not happen. If I opened multiple files (with `emacs -Q *.org`, then the error happened. I need to explore this more to see what is going on, and report the results. Thanks for the pointer.